# Webscraping DraftKings

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape odds off https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/basketball/nba by running

```
table = response.xpath('//*[@class="[sportsbook-table__body"]')
rows = table[1].xpath(‘//tr’)
rows[1].xpath(‘td//div//text()’)[1].extract()
```

as a test, but nothing shows up.

The table looks like this

```
<table class=sportsbook-table">
    <thead class="sportsbook-table__head"
        <tbody class="sportsbook-table__body"
            <tr class>
            ...
            <tr class>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: the page is dynamically created. You are pulling the static html. You'll need to grab the data from the source (api) directly, or use something like Selenium to let the page render, and then parse it.